# What is a Windows 8 'Child Session'?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, terminal-services

I'm currently writing a broker service which launches a process into arbitrary sessions based on certain criteria. Upon looking up the documentation for one of the APIs I use, I noticed that some new APIs have been added for Windows 8, controlling some new 'child session' feature ([WTSIsChildSessionsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WTSEnableChildSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh769143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WTSGetChildSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

The problem is that this new 'child session' feature is not documented anywhere as far as I can tell. I'd like to be able to 'future proof' my app and support this new technology if it's relevant to my application, but I can't figure out if it's relevant if I don't know what it is!

Does anyone know what exactly this is, or has a link to somewhere with some more information? (I ran searches on MSDN and Technet and came up empty-handed...)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have anything official, but a search for ["remote desktop" "child session"] indicates that people use the term "child session" to refer to a remote desktop session that is opened from another remote desktop session. So if you connect to server A from your machine and then connect to server B from within that RDP session, the connection from A to B would be a child session.

Comment: I suspect this might also be related to the emulator for Windows 8 apps. It runs a separate session for the logged-in user under which an app under development runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three of the MSDN pages to which you link contain the following remark.  The linked page describes the Child Sessions feature.

> For more information about child sessions, see [Child Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553447.aspx).

I would guess that this features was added to support "simulator" debugging of Windows 8 Apps.

Comment: I think that this is a recent documentation update, because the page on Child Sessions was not present when I posted this question... Nevertheless, thank you for answering! I never would've known the documentation had been updated otherwise.

Comment: @RaptorFactor:  Ah, now I understand the question a bit better... I was wondering how one could miss that link :-)  (I saw this question on the front page yesterday due to the edit; I just assumed it was a new question... bad assumption)